# floating div without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a floating div when user scrolling the contents, It almost working but getting little delay on the animation, I need that the floating div should animate along with scroll when scrollTop reach the floating div

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");

$(window).scroll(function(){            
    var y = $(this).scrollTop(),
        maxY = $('#footer').offset().top,
        scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height();
    if(y< maxY-scrollHeight ){
        $scrollingDiv
        .stop()
        .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"}, "fast" );        
    }    
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mn49tyzn/1/)

Comment: I fear you need to make the div `position: fixed;` or in future (or with polyfills)  `position: sticky;`

Comment: due to some CSS issues, I can't use 'position: fixed;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues that you can change:

1. Using JavaScript to animate DOM is usually slow.
   Change the animate function to CSS: transform: translateY()
2. Select items from DOM outside of the scroll function, so it will be done only 
   once.

```js
 var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");
 var $footer = $('#footer');
 var $window = $(window);
 
$(window).scroll(function(){            
    var y = $(this).scrollTop(),
        maxY = $footer.offset().top,
        scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height();
    if(y< maxY-scrollHeight ){
        $scrollingDiv        
        .css({"transform": "translateY(" + ($window.scrollTop()) + "px)"});        
    }    
});
```

[see the fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/qfpL0fk6/)